# How to make text and image contained in div when div shrinks?

Tags: html, css, frontend, position, styles

Currently, when I shrink the size of the screen, the text and images get squeezed out of the div like so: [image].

How can I fix it to look like [image: this]? (showing both full screen and half size of the screen).

```css
.flex {
  z-index: 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: #000000;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: -450px 36% 0 36%;
}

.landingText {
  z-index: 2;
  font-family: 'Mukta', sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 44px;
  line-height: 100%;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 27px 0 29px 33px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.landingArrow {
  display: inline-block;
  text-shadow: none;
  padding: 40px 0 29px 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div className={indexStyles.flex}>
  <h1 className={indexStyles.landingText}>LISTEN TO ORCAS LIVE!</h1>
  <div className={indexStyles.landingArrow}>
    <Image src={arrow} />
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: the app is built with NextJS so the HTML I posted is not what my browser sees on completion of the script. I screenshotted the HTML from inspect elements:
[image]

Comment: The "HTML" you've posted isn't HTML; it's a part of whatever framework you're using to generate the HTML. Can you post the HTML that your browser sees on completion of the script?

Comment: @DavidThomas Yes, it's built with NextJS. I updated with a picture of HTML cuz I can't copy

Answer (score 0):

Took from another answer but this should do the trick

If the container is the body, what you are looking for is Viewport-percentage lengths:

The viewport-percentage lengths are relative to the size of the initial containing block. When the height or width of the initial containing block is changed, they are scaled accordingly. However, when the value of overflow on the root element is auto, any scroll bars are assumed not to exist.

The values are:

vw (% of the viewport width)
vh (% of the viewport height)
vi (1% of the viewport size in the direction of the root element's inline axis)
vb (1% of the viewport size in the direction of the root element's block axis)
vmin (the smaller of vw or vh)
vmax (the larger or vw or vh)
1 v* is equal to 1% of the initial containing block.

Using it looks like this:

```
p {
    font-size: 4vw;
}
```

As you can see, when the viewport width increases, so do the font-size, without needing to use media queries.

These values are a sizing unit, just like px or em, so they can be used to size other elements as well, such as width, margin, or padding.

Browser support is pretty good, but you'll likely need a fallback, such as:

```
p {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 4vw;
}
```

Comment: you're not answering my question...